# angular required validations on forms based on conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a part on my code where I only set some fields as required. By default only the emailAddress is a requied field but I have condition in my app where setting firstName , lastName , companyName as required.

If res.isSuccess === true that is the time I only want to set firstname , lastname , company name as required.

But the problem is as you can see on the screenshow below , the mat error message is already showing upon intial load(the red one) it should only show if for example firstname field is touch or clicked so the message should not show by default.

Any idea guys about this issue ? Thank you.

#html

```
 <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 26px;">
                                <mat-label>First Name *</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
                                <mat-error
                                    *ngIf="modelForm.get('firstName').hasError('required')  && (modelForm.get('firstName').touched || modelForm.get('firstName').dirty)">
                                    First Name is required.
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
```

```
     getStarted() {
        this.AccountRoleDetails = null;
        if (this.userService) {
          this.userService
            .getUserEmail(this.accountId, this.modelForm.value['emailAddress'])
            .subscribe(
              (res: any) => {
                if (
                  res.isSuccess === true 
                ) 
              this.setRequiredVlidations();
    
    
    {
.........
```

#Code

```
initFormGroup() {
    this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [this.model.id || 0],
      emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
      firstName: this.model.firstName,
      roleId: this.model.roleId,
      lastName: this.model.lastName,
      phoneNumber: this.model.phoneNumber,
      companyName: this.model.companyName,
    });
  }
```

#code 2

```
setRequiredVlidations() {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required);

    this.modelForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out

```
this.modelForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

This may be causing the Angular Reactive forms to check the value, which if it's empty, will not be valid if it's "required".

In your mat-error html tag, try separating out that logic tree to be clearer:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="(modelForm.get('firstName').hasError('required') && 
    modelForm.get('firstName').touched) || 
    modelForm.get('firstName').dirty">
        First Name is required.
</mat-error>
```

You could also try changing up your logic here:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.controls.firstName.invalid &&
                  modelForm.controls.firstName.dirty">
        First Name is required.
</mat-error>
```

Or:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.controls.firstName.invalid &&
                  modelForm.controls.firstName.touched">
        First Name is required.
</mat-error>
```

Depending on your UI/UX requirements.

This will help you more clearly see exactly why it is returning an invalid status. Use the browser console and do some inspecting.

Also try using your browser tools to actually see the form field validation errors and values and validity status of that field before and after setting the new validators. The "required" status may be accessed differently than you are doing it.

Can you post these values you get from the browser console and update your question?

Comment: Still the same after removing the  this.modelForm.updateValueAndValidity();
 https://imgur.com/a/TAGfJqk

Comment: Please see my latest edit, and check the values of the reactive forms fields in the browser console or using breakpoints.

Comment: The mat error message sir is no longer showing your answer above is correct but the field is still red by defaul https://imgur.com/a/LOAqxKs

Comment: red line should not show by default same with the mat error message

Comment: Tim, now try to remove the updateValueAndValidity call. Does that remove the red?

Comment: it does not remove the red Sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235457/discussion-between-cklimowski-and-tim-launders).